# A Weak Law of Large Numbers for a Markov non-iid Random Process

Tags: probability, markov-chains, law-of-large-numbers

Consider the sequence $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. We have that marginally $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = 1/2$, $\mathbb{P}(X_i = -1) = 1/2$. The sequence is Markov such that $\mathbb{P}(X_{i} = X_{i-1}) = 1-p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_{i} = -X_{i-1}) = p$.

When $p = 1/2$, the sequence is i.i.d, and we can prove the weak law:
$$ 
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}X_i = \frac{S_n}{n} \rightarrow 0\;\;\text{(in probability)}
$$
simply via the Markov inequality. For $0<p<1$, we can prove a strong law by noting that the sequence is generated by an aperiodic, irreducible Markov chain with stationary distribution [1/2, 1/2]. It should thus be possible to prove a weak law for general $0<p<1$. But, if we follow the same method as in the case of $p=1/2$, we have:

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left(\frac{S_n}{n} - 0\right)^2 > \epsilon^2\right) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[S_n^2]}{n^2\epsilon^2}.
$$
For $p=1/2$, $\mathbb{E}[S_n^2] = n$, completing the proof. But in general:

$$
\mathbb{E}[S_n^2] = n + 2\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i>j}^n \mathbb{E}[X_iX_j].
$$

Is it possible to show that this second term grows slower than $n^2$? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Convergence almost surely implies convergence in probability.

Comment: Yes, thus, a weak law should hold true as well. My question is about if it is possible to prove a weak law directly using a similar approach to the i.i.d case.